# Laurent Series about a point

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I go about calculating the Laurent series of $$\frac{z}{z^2 + 4}$$ about $z=2i$?

I did partial fractions to arrive at
$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{z+2i} + \frac{1}{z-2i}\right).$$ But I'm not sure where to go from here. Do I use the general taylor series form and then substitute $n$ for $-m$? And how would it work about $2i$, as only one of the fractions has that point as a singularity.

[SIDE NOTE - The definition of Laurent series is the summation from -infinity to +infinity, so why is it that series from -infinity to +1 (for example) are also called laurent series? Are they really just any series that run from -inifity to a positive number?]

Comment: added $\LaTeX$ check if I made it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ the coefficient may be $0$. 
Note that the geometric series for $|z|<1$
$$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n $$
scale your fraction and use my hint.

And a hint, for not doing to much work, 
$$\frac{1}{z-2i}=(z-2i)^{-1}$$
is already a part of $a_{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Dominic Michaelis' answer is good, but I might also think about this:
$$
\frac{1}{4+z^2} = \frac{1/4}{1-\left(\frac z2\right)^2} = \frac14\left(1-\frac z2 + \frac{z^2}{4}-\frac{z^3}{8}+\cdots \right)
$$

Comment: This is not about $z=2i$.